# SQL Regex for 7 digit number in varchar field

Tags: sql-server, wildcard

Question:
What's the best way to 'extract' all Rows where the TEXT column contains a 7 digit number starting with 7 and only show the 7 digit number?

SQL Server 2017:

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE_1] (
TEXT varchar(50) Null,
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(TEXT)
VALUES
('7005011'),
('The Number is 7335022'),
('asd*.-: wqe'),
('/7225033/.123'),
('Nr.: 7115044')
;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b808ea)

The desired result would be:

```
+---------+
| TEXT    |
+---------+
| 7005011 |
| 7335022 |
| 7225033 |
| 7115044 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Have a look at `LIKE` and `PATINDEX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no RegEx in SQL Server natively, you need to use `PATINDEX`, `SUBSTRING`, and `LIKE`:

```
SELECT [TEXT] = SUBSTRING([TEXT], 
  PATINDEX('%7' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 6) + '%', [TEXT]), 7)
FROM dbo.TABLE_1
WHERE [TEXT] LIKE '%7' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 6) + '%';
```

Output:

| TEXT |
| --- |
| 7005011 |
| 7335022 |
| 7225033 |
| 7115044 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7dffb98ad3890b547f555929f1bc773)

Comment: The query also includes numbers with leading 8 or 9 but I can work quite well from here on. I had weird results with like and [0-9]% attempts and I didn't know about PATINDEX. Thanks

Comment: @PeterS I see, sorry, I got messed up about the 7 and thought it was just referencing _the length of the number_. If you also want it to not return rows where the number starts with 7 and is _longer_ than 7 digits, [that's an easy change too](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8219b0aa2dee518377a820ec8d81842d). These all assume that in any tuple there's only one instance of a number that starts with 7 and is >= 7 digits long.